# Filter alpha with ColorMatrixColorFilter

Tags: android, colormatrix

I want to filter color with ColorMatrixColorFilter.
I have already a code working well but... I doesn't work for alpha.

```
static private ColorMatrixColorFilter getFilter(int backgroundColor, int foregroundColor)
{
    float rB = (float) (Color.red(backgroundColor)) / 255;
    float gB = (float) (Color.green(backgroundColor)) / 255;
    float bB = (float) (Color.blue(backgroundColor)) / 255;

    float rF = (float) (Color.red(foregroundColor)) / 255;
    float gF = (float) (Color.green(foregroundColor)) / 255;
    float bF = (float) (Color.blue(foregroundColor)) / 255;

    float[] colorTransform = { rB - rF, 0, 0, 0, rF * 255, 0, gB - gF, 0, 0, gF * 255, 0, 0, bB - bF, 0, bF * 255, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(colorTransform);

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);

}
```

How can I do for alpha ?
Because here, alpha is always "1".

Thanks.

Comment: You're clearly aware that the last four entries in this array form the alpha component of the color matrix in the filter- so I read this that you want the alpha component to be proportionate to the amount of blue. If so, can I humbly suggest that the range for the alpha component in Android might be [0,255] rather than [0,1]? At least, I think that's what I remember from last time I was Androiding. So try [...0,0,255,0]. Best.

Comment: Hum how can I explain that... It's a multiplication, so the calcul is = alpha (here 1) * alpha image. But, with that, we can't have differents alpha for background image and foreground image...

Comment: Oh sorry was being incredibly stupid reading too quickly before typing. You know how when you've seen someone get this wrong before so you see it everywhere? That. Best.